# ant conditional targets and 'recursion'

Tags: coding-style, ant, if-statement, dependencies

I'm fairly new to ant, and I've seen uncle Bob's "extract until you drop" episode.

As a result I try to define ant-targets as small as possibly possible, so you can see exactly the essence of the target, and no more.  For more details, you have to refer to sub-targets.

Whether that's good or bad style is a different debate (or a flame-war maybe).

Therefore, I was creating a build script that, in pseudo-code, would look like this:

```
build =
   compile
   instrument if coverage
```

The `coverage` task is split into subtargets, too:

```
coverage:
   create-coverage-dirs
   call-cobertura
```

EDIT- I want to express that `coverage` sub-targets should not be run.

But... I'm having a hard time expressing this 'cleanly' in ant-ese.

Assuming that I can use the `depends` attribute to indicate ... inter-target dependencies, I got to something like this:

```
<target name="build" depends="compile, coverage"/>

<target name="compile"> .... </target>

<target name="coverage" depends="
       create-coverage-dirs, 
       taskdef-cobertura"
 if="build.with.coverage">

  <cobertura-instrument ...> ... </cobertura-instrument>

</target>

<target name="create-coverage-dirs">
  ...    
</target>

<target name="taskdef-cobertura">
  ...
</target>
```

Whow this looked nice!

Only it seemed that, when executing, the `coverage` task was duefully omitted, but **it's sub-tasks were still executed** when `build.with.coverage` was `false`!

```
>ant -v compile
Build sequence for target(s) `build' is 
  [compile, create-coverage-dirs, taskdef-    cobertura, coverage, build]
Complete build sequence is 
  [compile, create-coverage-dirs, taskdef-cobertura, coverage,    build, ]
```

I can put an `if` attribute in every coverage sub-task, but that doesn't seem clean to me.

So here's the question:

1. Is my ant-ese a horrible dialect?  Am I 'making ant into make'?
2. Should `if` be used this way, or is there an `if-and-recurse` kind-of attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a property at all in this case, but rely solely on `depends` (which seems more natural to me for this task):

```
<target name="build" depends="compile, coverage"/>

<target name="compile"> ...

<target name="coverage" 
        depends="compile, instrument,
                 create-coverage-dirs, taskdef-cobertura"> ...
```

Comment: That's my feeling, too.  Only that `coverage` also depends on `compile`, no?

Answer (score 3):

Repeat after me: *Ant is not a programming language*. In fact, write it down 100 times on the blackboard.

Ant is not a programming language, so don't think of it as such. It is a build dependency matrix.

It's difficult for programmers to wrap their heads around that idea. They want to tell Ant each step and when it should be done. They want loops, if statements. They'll resort to having a `build.sh` script to call various targets in Ant because you can't easily program Ant.

In Ant, you specify discrete tasks, and which tasks depend upon other tasks, and let Ant handle where and when things get executed.

What I am saying is that you don't normally split tasks into sub-tasks and then try calling `<ant>` or `<subant>` on them.

Have discrete tasks, but then let each task know what other tasks they depend upon. Also remember that there is no true order in Ant. When you list the `depends=` tasks, there is no guarantee which order they'll be executed in.

---

Standard Ant Style (which means the way I do it (aka The Right Way), and not the way my colleague does it (aka The Wrong Way)), normally states to define tasks at the top of the properties file and not in any target. Here's a basic outline on how I structure my `build.xml`:

```
<project name=...>

      <!-- Build Properties File -->
      <property name="build.properties.file"
           value="${basedir}/build.properties"/>
      <property file="${build.properties.file"/>

      <!-- Base Java Properties -->
      <property name="..." value="..."/>

      <taskdef/>
      <taskdef/>

      <!-- Javac properties -->
      <property name="javac..."  value="..."/>

      <task/>
      <task/>
 </project>
```

This creates an interesting hierarchy. If you have a file called `build.properties`, it will override the properties as defined in the `build.xml` script. For example, you have:

```
<property name="copy.verbose"   value="false"/>

<copy todir="${target}"
   verbose="${copy.verbose}">
   <fileset dir="${source}"/>
</copy>
```

You can turn on the verbose copy by merely setting `copy.verbose = true` in your `build.properties` file. And, you can specify a different build properties file by merely specifying this on the command line:

```
$ ant -Dbuild.properties.file="my.build.properties"
```

*(Yes, yes, I know there's a `-property`command line parameter for `ant`)*

I normally set the various values in the `build.xml` to the assumed defaults, but anyone can change them by creating a `build.properties` file. And, since all the base properties are at the beginning, they're easy to find.

Tasks are defined in this non-target space too. That way, I can easily find the definition since they're in the same place in each `build.xml`, and I know I can use a task without worrying whether the task defining target has been hit.

Now, to your question:

Define your tasks (and don't have a tar defining task, or you'll drive yourself crazy). Then, define the dependencies on each of those tasks. Developers can select the targets they want to hit. For example:

```
<project>
   <description>
      yadda, yadda, yadda
   </description>

   <taskdef name="cobertura"/>

   <target name="compile"
        description="Compile the code"/>

    <!-- Do you have to compile code before you run Cobertura?--> 
    <target name="coverage"
       description="Calculate test coverage"
       depends="compile">

       <mkdir dir="${coverage.dir}"/>
       <cobertura-instrument/>
    </target>
<project>
```

If you want to compile your code, but not run any tests, you execute `ant` with  the `compile` target. If you want to run tests, you execute `ant` with a `coverage` target. There's no need for the `depends=` parameter.

Also notice the `description=` parameter and the `<description>` task. That's because if you do this:

```
$ ant -p
```

Ant will show what's in the `<description>` task, all targets with a `description` parameter, and that description. This way, developers know what targets to use for what tasks.

By the way, I also recommend *doing things the right way* (aka doing it the way I do it) and name your targets after the [Maven lifecycle goals](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics). Why? Because it was a good way to standardize on the names of targets. Developers know that `clean` will remove all built artifacts, and `compile` will run the `<javac>` task, and that `test` will run the `junit` tests. Thus, you should use the goals in the [Cobertura plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html): `cobertura`.

---

## Edit

> my problem is: I regard 'coverage' as related to 'optimized' and 'debug', i.e. a build flavor. That's where my difficulty lies: for Java, coverage results in an an extra intermediate target in the compile step.

I'm looking at the Corburta page, and there's no real change in the `<javac>` task (which is part of the *compile* target.

Instead, you run Corburtura on the already built `.class` files, and then run your `<junit>` task. The big change is in your `<junit>` task which must now include references to your Corburtura jars, and to your instrumented classes.

I imagine you could have a `corburtura`target or what ever you want to call it. This target runs the instrumented JUnit tests. This is the target you want developers to hit, and should contain a description that it runs instrumented tests.

Of course, you can't run the instrumented Junit tests without first instrumenting them. Thus, your `corburtura` target will depend upon another `instrument.tests` target. This target is internal. People who run your `build.xml` don't normally say "instrument tests" without running those tests. Thus, this target has no description.

Of course, the `instrument.tests` target depends upon having `.class` files to instrument, so it will have a dependency upon the `compile` target that runs the `<javac>` task:

```
<target name="instrument.classes"
   depends="compile">
   <coburtura-instrument/>
</target>

<target name="corburtura"
   depends="instrument.classes"
   description="Runs the JUnit tests instrumented with Corburtura">
   <junit/>
</target>
```

The only problem is that you're specifying your `<junit>` target twice: Once when instrumented, and once for normal testing. This might be a minor issue. If you update how your JUnit tests run, you have to do it in two places.

If you want to solve this issue, you can use `<macrodef>` to define a JUnit test running Macro. I used what was on the [Corbertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html) page to help with the outline. Completely non-tested and probably full of syntax errors:

```
<target name="instrument.tests"
    depends="compile">
    <corburtura-instrument/>
</target>

<target name="corburtura"
    depends="instrument.tests"
    description="Instrument and run the JUnit tests">

    <run.junit.test fork.flag="true">
        <systemproperty.addition>
            <sysproperty key="net.sourceforge.corbertura.datafile"
                file="${basedir}/cobertura.ser" />
        </systemproperty.addition>
        <pre.classpath>
            <classpath location="${instrumented.dir}" />
        </pre.classpath>
        <post.classpath>
            <classpath refid="cobertura_classpath" />
        </post.classpath>
    </run.junit.test>
</target>

<target name="test"
    description="Runs the Junit tests without any instrumentation">
    <run.junit.test/>
</target>

<macrodef name="run.junit.test">
    <attribute name="fork.flag" default="false"/>
    <element name="sysproperty.addition" optional="yes"/>
    <element name="pre.classpath" optional="yes"/>
    <element name="post.classpath" optional="yes"/>
    <sequential>
        <junit fork="@{fork.flag}" dir="${basedir}" failureProperty="test.failed">

            <systemproperty.addtion/>
            <pre.classpath/>
            <classpath location="${classes.dir}" />
            <post.classpath/>

            <formatter type="xml" />
            <test name="${testcase}" todir="${reports.xml.dir}" if="testcase" />
            <batchtest todir="${reports.xml.dir}" unless="testcase">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Whoa thanks for this elaborate answer.  I totally agree with the `depends=` i.s.o. `antcall`; my problem is: I regard 'coverage' as related to 'optimized' and 'debug', i.e. a build flavor.  That's where my difficulty lies: for Java, coverage results in an **an extra intermediate target** in the compile step.

Comment: Just like e.g. I'm not interested in the non-optimized code when doing a release build, I don't need any of the javac output lingering around.

Comment: By the way- I called the build style 'coverage' iso 'cobertura' since I want to specify **what it does** iso **who does it**.  That's _the right way for me_ since I'm also doing a C++ build with the same semantics.

Comment: It has been a while since I've used Corbertura, but I don't remember any changes in the `<javac>` task. Instead, you take the `.class` files generated in `<javac>`, and _instrument_ them using Cobertura. The real change is in the `<junit>` task when you have to fork Junit, incorporate the instrumented classes in the classpath, and include all the special Corbertura jars. You can simply run `<junit>` as part of your Corbertura target. You can either duplicate it, or use `<macrodef>` to define `<junit>`, so you can use parameters to specify (or not specify) the Cobertura changes. See above.

Answer (score 1):

The [if attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless) tests if the property exists, not if it is true or false.  If you don't want to run the coverage target then don't define the property `build.with.coverage`.

As of Ant 1.8.0 you can use property expansion to resplver property as a boolean:

```
<target name="coverage" depends="
           create-coverage-dirs, 
           taskdef-cobertura"
        if="${build.with.coverage}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the info; even with `build.with.coverage` not defined, the only target that's excluded is the 'main' `coverage` target.  I want to express that it's sub-targets shouldn't be run either.

Comment: You can remove the sub targets from the depends list and call them instead via [antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) from inside the coverage task.

Comment: Antcall is not the same as depends: <antcall> will not override existing references, even if you set inheritRefs to true. As the called build files is the same build file as the calling one, this means it will not override any reference set via an id attribute at all. The only references that can be inherited by the child project are those defined by nested <reference> elements or references defined by tasks directly (not using the id attribute). See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html

Comment: Yes I can, but that does imply I dictate the order of execution.  I was trying to avoid that, but maybe I _am_ turning ant into make...

Comment: `depends` also dictates the order of execution: http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html

Comment: @michael667: yes!  The build system determines the order all by itself!  That's a lot better than letting me myself decide.

Comment: You're deciding already by writing your targets in the `depends` attribute in a certain order. Anyway, I prefer `depends` over `antcall` or properties in this case, see my dedicated answer to your question

Comment: @michael667: no, according to the reference, the execution order is _not_ determined by the declaration order - and a good thing, too.

Comment: @xtofl: The execution order might not be the same as the declaration order in `depends`, but declaration order definitely matters in the computation of the execution order: `depends = "a, b"` is not similar to `depends = "b, a"`